# Show full text of running queries in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to see the full text of running queries in PostgreSQL.

When I run this command `SELECT procpid,current_query FROM pg_stat_activity ORDER BY procpid;` in dbshell it shows running queries, but for long queries, it does not show complete query.

For example, if a query has a long text, it does not show the complete text of the query, it only shows 1024 characters of the query and not more.

I want to know is there any way to show the complete query?

Comment: It seems like it was a bug on 9.0 see here http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1329649956.2292.7.camel@localhost.localdomain

Comment: The version of postgresql on my server is 9.1. Does it exist in 9.1 too?

Comment: Change the title to: "Show full text of running query in postgresql"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a line in file postgresql.conf:

```
track_activity_query_size = 1024
```

After increasing this variable you will get more characters. Tested on postgresql 9.1. Changing above line requires restarting server.

Comment: FWIW, I usually bump that to between 6000 and 8000 (we have some reasonably large queries)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, at least not on Amazon's RDS version of Postgres. I set this value to 8000, rebooted my instance, yet it's still truncating the query to 264 characters...